# What is this dome used for?

Tags: radio-communications

I have seen this dome on the top of some 737-800 airplanes and am curious to know  what is it for. Is the a communication antenna for the satellite connection and in-flight internet that some airlines are providing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That fairing covers an antenna for a satellite-based Wi-Fi system.